# Отсутствие данных заменить на 0

Tags: php, mysql

Вот отрывок кода.

```
for ($g =0; $g++<$idg;) {
    $ch = mysql_query("SELECT chips FROM reit WHERE 
    id_games='$g' AND id_users='1' ",$db);
    while ($chg = mysql_fetch_array($ch)) {
    $chg = $chg['chips'];
    echo "<td>$chg </td>";
    }
}
```

Когда он выполняется выводит столбик `chips (323, 5454, 45345, 43234)`, но, допустим, сделать выборку  `id_games` и `id_users`  там, где нет данных `chips`, он будет выводить то же самое, только без столбика, там, где не оказалось данных. А как сделать чтоб когда он видит, что ничего нет, менял ничего на 0 в переменную `$chg`?
Если разобрать цикл, получается так:

```
select chips from reit where id_users = '1' and id_games = '1';
43432
select chips from reit where id_users = '1' and id_games = '2';
пусто
select chips from reit where id_users = '1' and id_games = '3';
434234
select chips from reit where id_users = '1' and id_games = '2';
987
```

Но выведет он 43432 434234 987.
При этом рушится вся таблица.
Пытался сделать условия, но оно не работает

```
if ($chg == '') {
  $chg = '0';
}
```

Comment: `select coalesce(chip, 0) FROM reit...`

Answer (score 1):

```
select IFNULL(chips, 0) AS chips from reit
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте для случая если в chips пустое значение:

```
$chg = $chg['chips']?$chg['chips']:0;
```

или в запросе:

```
SELECT if(chips,chips,0) as chips FROM reit WHERE id_games='$g' AND id_users='1'
```

**upd:** если же нулевая выборка то как верно комментирует [[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz)

```
SELECT coalesce(chip, 0) FROM reit WHERE id_games='$g' AND id_users='1'
```

Comment: что то все равно не работает(((

Comment: Скорее всего это не тот случай. И надо анализировать mysql_num_rows($ch). Если 0 -- ничего не найдено, то... http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php

А coalesce тут вряд ли поможет. Это если бы строка была, а значение chips для неё было NULL -- тады ой.

Comment: @Alexander666 с там ником, и чтоб работало?

Comment: Перефразируй

Comment: Дык 666 мешает. А не идёт с каким вариантом? coalesce? см. мой комментарий выше.